# Developing for Windows 6.5

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, installation

I have just got a new company mobile and would like to begin developing apps for the HTC HD2 Mobile Phone. However, when I downloaded Microsoft Windows Phone Developer Tools, it pretty much said right at the end of installation that "Setup could not install correctly", and I clicked on "more", and it said "Silverlight 4.0 could not install correctly". So, the fact that Windows Phone Dev Tools couldn't install completely was because of this Silverlight 4 that couldn't install!

Has anyone had the same problems, if so, how did you resolve this issue (if you did)?

And... Is there another way to develop applications for mobile phones running the Windows Operating System other than XNA and Windows Dev Tools? Even better... Could it be done simply using the current Visual Studio Express C# Edition I already have?

Thanks All

Comment: If you really did want the WP7 tools, try installing silverlight 4 - that will fix the silverlight 4 not installed issue. The Windows Phone Dev Tools are only at the technology preview stage so the odd bug is expected.

Comment: Silverlight has issues atm, and does not want to install. I've given up on trying to develop for Windows Mobile, and have instead purchased a new HTC Desire mobile (runs Android).I've given up on Windows. Had enough.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to develop for Windows Mobile 6.5? 
If so, you need Visual Studio 2008 and the [Windows Mobile 6.5 Developer Tool Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=20686a1d-97a8-4f80-bc6a-ae010e085a6e&displaylang=en)

The Microsoft Windows Phone Developer Tools you downloaded is to develop for Windows Phone 7, the next version of Windows for smartphones. You won't be able to target WM6.5 with it.

Comment: Bear in mind that the WP6 dev tools need VS 2008 Proffesional - they don't work with the express version as far as I know.

Comment: It's not for the actual Windows Phone itself (the one by microsoft), it's actually for the HTC HD2 Mobile (Which came with Windows 6.5 on it. :-)

Comment: I don't understand the downvote ?
There is no Windows Phone by Microsoft as such, Windows Phone IS the OS. 
The smartphone built by MS is the Kin.
I know that the HTC HD2 came with WM 6.5 and the tools needed to develop applications for WM6.5 is Visual Studio 2008 with the WM SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop on HTC HD2 which have Windows Mobile 6.5, you must download Windows Mobile 6 SDK (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=06111a3a-a651-4745-88ef-3d48091a390b&displaylang=en) and probably Windows Mobile 6.5 Developer Tool Kit.

You need also need Windows Mobile Device Center if you don't have it already.

Windows Phone Developer Tools which you downlaoded is for development on Windows Phone 7.